# Apply DataTrigger Setter only if the element is visible

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have two text boxes, combo box, and a save button. If user selects specific value of the combo box second text box becomes visible. I have validation rule that checks if the text box is empty or white space and if it is, it disabled the save button.

```
<Style x:Key="okButtonEnabler" TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Text, ElementName=FirstTextBox, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource IsButtonEnabledConverter}}" Value="0">
                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Text, ElementName=SecondTextBox, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource IsButtonEnabledConverter}}" Value="0">
                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

<TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="2" Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource validationTemplate}" Name="FirstTextBox"
            Style="{StaticResource textBoxInError}">
                <TextBox.Text>
                    <Binding Path="FirstValue">
                        <Binding.ValidationRules>
                            <validationRules:EmptyStringValidationRule ErrorMessage="Must enter first value" />
                        </Binding.ValidationRules>
                    </Binding>
               </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>

<TextBox  Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Visibility="{Binding IsSecondValueSelected, Converter={StaticResource SecondTextBoxVisiblityConverter}}" Margin="2" Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource validationTemplate}"
            Style="{StaticResource textBoxInError}" Name="SecondTextBox">
                <TextBox.Text>
                    <Binding Path="SecondValue">
                        <Binding.ValidationRules>
                            <validationRules:EmptyStringValidationRule ErrorMessage="Must enter second value" />
                        </Binding.ValidationRules>
                    </Binding>
                </TextBox.Text>
            </TextBox>
```

So right now, no matter if the second text box is visible or not, the data trigger will apply and the button will be disabled until the second text box is not empty. I want this scenario only if the second text box is visible.

Answer (score 2):

Use MultiDataTrigger to combine more than one condition

ex:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="okButtonEnabler"
               TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled"
                    Value="True" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding Text, ElementName=FirstTextBox, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource IsButtonEnabledConverter}}" Value="0" />
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding Text, ElementName=SecondTextBox, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource IsButtonEnabledConverter}}"
                                   Value="0" />
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>

                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled"
                            Value="False" />
                </MultiDataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>

    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>

        <TextBox Grid.Row="1"
                 Grid.Column="1"
                 Margin="2"
                 Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource validationTemplate}"
                 Name="FirstTextBox"
                 Style="{StaticResource textBoxInError}">
            <TextBox.Text>
                <Binding Path="FirstValue">
                    <Binding.ValidationRules>
                        <validationRules:EmptyStringValidationRule ErrorMessage="Must enter first value" />
                    </Binding.ValidationRules>
                </Binding>
            </TextBox.Text>
        </TextBox>

        <TextBox  Grid.Row="2"
                  Grid.Column="1"
                  Visibility="{Binding IsSecondValueSelected, Converter={StaticResource SecondTextBoxVisiblityConverter}}"
                  Margin="2"
                  Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource validationTemplate}"
                  Style="{StaticResource textBoxInError}"
                  Name="SecondTextBox">
            <TextBox.Text>
                <Binding Path="SecondValue">
                    <Binding.ValidationRules>
                        <validationRules:EmptyStringValidationRule ErrorMessage="Must enter second value" />
                    </Binding.ValidationRules>
                </Binding>
            </TextBox.Text>
        </TextBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Correct! And you beat me to it.  I was going to use SecondTextBox.Visibility for the second condition, but either should work: <Condition Binding="{Binding Visibility, ElementName=SecondTextBox}" Value="Visible" />